# xcode switching views with button it freezes screen with long error

Tags: iphone

Help! I have been making a app and when I made a button and typed in the code for it to switch  and when i pushed the button it froze and gave me this error:

[ViewController pushBack]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7143500
2013-10-09 18:17:41.901 Test[2445:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController pushBack]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7143500'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1d1c4bd 0x1c80bbc 0x1c8094e 0x10e2705 0x162c0 0x16258 0xd7021 0xd757f 0xd66e8 0x45cef 0x45f02 0x23d4a 0x15698 0x1becdf9 0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5 0x1c06962 0x1c37bb6 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1beb7e3 0x1beb668 0x12ffc 0x2952 0x2885 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
This is my code:

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)pushButton; {

```
Game *screen = [[Game alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:^{ }];
[screen release];
```

}

That was my viewcontroller.m

and i did hook up all the IBActions to the xib file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app crashed because your IBAction is pushButton and the selector you are trying to invoke is pushBack. (Not quite sure if  ' ;' after method name is typo error or your code is like that.)Two solutions :

```
1)Change your method name to pusBack (without any arguments)
2)Change the name of selector hooked to button to pushButton.
```

The Xcode freezes because your app crashed and is now terminated. You will experience this in your day to day life.Welcome to iOS programming.